# Me retorna false el password_verify()

Tags: php, mysql

Hola estoy haciendo una practica a sobre cifrado de datos con php, todo funciona mas o menos correcto excepto cuando verifico con un bucle la comprobación del registro. Me retorna false en todos los casos en el momento de la comprobación:

**Problema**:cuando voy a comrprobar el login, si escribo uno de los usuarios de prueba que es MANUEL y la contraseña 1234 o ANTONIO-123456 me sale que no está registrado y sí lo está. Entonces no se si el bucle lo configure mal o algo que no funciona.

Este es el formulario que comprueba el login:

**comprueba_login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, user-
    scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

   <?php

    try{

        $login=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["usu"]));
        $password=htmlentities(addslashes($_POST["contra"]));

        $contador=0;

        $base=new PDO ("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas" , "root" , "");
        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $sql="SELECT * FROM USUARIOS_PASS WHERE USUARIOS= :login";

        $resultado= $base->prepare($sql);

        $resultado->execute(array  (":login"=>$login));

            while ($registro=$resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

               // echo "Usuario: " . $registro['USUARIOS'] . "Contraseña: " . $registro['PASSWORD'] . "<br>"  ; 

                if (password_verify($password, $registro['PASSWORD'])){

                    $contador++;
                }
            }

        if($contador>0){

            echo "Usuario registrado";

        }else{

            echo "Usuario no registrado";
        }

        $resultado->closeCursor();

    }catch(Exepcion $e){


        die ("Error:" . $e->getMessage());
    }

   ?>

</body>

</html>
```

A continuación adjunto la página de insertar usuarios:

**pagina_insertar_usuarios.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Documento sin título</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php

    $usuario= $_POST["usu"];
    $contrasenia= $_POST["contra"];

    $pass_cifrado=password_hash($contrasenia, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array("cost"=>12)); 


    try{

        $base=new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=pruebas', 'root', '');

        $base->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $base->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");      


        $sql="INSERT INTO USUARIOS_PASS (USUARIOS, PASSWORD) VALUES (:usu, :contra)";

        $resultado=$base->prepare($sql);        


        $resultado->execute(array(":usu"=>$usuario, ":contra"=>$pass_cifrado));     


        echo "Registro insertado";

        $resultado->closeCursor();

    }catch(Exception $e){           


        echo "Línea del error: " . $e->getLine();

    }finally{

        $base=null;


    }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Los formularios:

**Formulario_insertar_usuarios.php**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Documento sin título</title>

        <style>

        table{
            width:300px;
            margin:auto;
            background-color:#FFC;
            border:2px solid #F00;
            padding:5px;

        }

        td{
            text-align:center;

        }
        h1{text-align:center}

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>
    <h1>REGÍSTRATE</h1>

        <form action="pagina_insertar_usuarios.php" method="post">
        <table><tr>
          <td>
            Usuario</td><td><input type="text" name="usu" id="usu"></td></tr>
           <tr>
             <td> Contraseña </td><td><input type="text" name="contra" id="contra"></td></tr>

           <tr><td colspan="2"> <input type="submit" name="enviando" value="¡Dale!">
        </td></tr></table>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

El formulario de login:

**login.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="widht=device-width, user-
    scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximun-scale=1, minimun-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    <title>LOGIN</title>

    <style>

        h1{

            text-align: center;
        }

        table {

            width: 25%;
            background-color: darkorchid;
            margin: auto;
            border: 2px solid #4b184f;
        }

        .izq {

            text-align: right;

        }

        .der{

            text-align: left;
        }

        td{

            text-align: center;
            padding: 10px;
        }


    </style>


</head>

<body>

   <h1>INTRODUCE TUS DATOS:</h1>

   <form name="" action="comprueba_login.php" method="post" >

     <table>

         <tr>

             <td class="izq">Login: </td>
             <td class="der"><input type="text" name="usu"></td>
         </tr><tr><td class="izq">Password:</td><td class="der"><input type="password" name="contra" /></td></tr>

         <tr><td colspan="2"><input input type="submit" name="enviar" value="Log In" </td></tr>
     </table>


   </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Y sobre la base de datos utilizo xammp con valores de usuario sin modificar [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Podrías decir dónde está el problema exactamente?

Comment: Mi problema es que cuando voy a comrprobar el login, si escribo uno de los usuarios de prueba que es   MANUEL y la contraseña 1234 me sale que no está registrado y sí lo está. Entonces no se si el bucle lo configure mal o algo que no funciona.

Comment: Edité la pregunta al principio para que sea comprensible, gracias por tu aporte.

Comment: Estás trabajando equivocadamente, te recomiendo que leas [esta aportación en las Notas del Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-verify.php#121974) que explica los pasos que tienes que dar, 1º para guardar la clave debes usar `password_hash()`, 2º para hacer la comprobación usar `password_verify()`. Está muy bien explicado paso por paso. Otro aspecto que podría ser problemático en el uso abusivo de `htmlentities()` y de `addslashes()`, digo abusivo porque **no lo necesitas**, las consultas preparadas te blindan contra  código malicioso para este caso.

Comment: Lo que me explica en la pagina que comentas me ayuda a entender el código de cifrado, yo cuando e creado el bucle que me has linkeado, yo lo he dividido en dos, 1 para recorrer el array de la lista de usuarios, y el segundopara crear el bucle del que habla en la pagina mencionada que me has linkado, el problema viene que no se porqué, cuando realizo la consulta preparada (ya le he quitado los slashes, pero he dejado las variables declaradas al principio con $_POST  para que en el array tal y como explica tu enlace, no se vea tan cargado.

Comment: No es cuestión de cargado o no cargado, sino de que no necesitas aplicar esas funciones de filtrado porque no se necesitan, además, podrían modificar cualquier dato haciendo que el dato a comparar no sea válido. Por otra parte, **cuando guardas la clave con el `INSERT` debes crear un `hash`  e insertar ESE `hash` en la tabla**, no veo que haces eso en tu código, es el 1er punto de mi comentario anterior y que es explicado con claridad en el enlace. Si no combinas ambas prácticas las comparaciones no van a coincidir.

Comment: Ignora la segunda parte de mi comentario anterior, lo del hash en la inserción está bien como lo tienes.

Comment: Sugiero que edites la pregunta mostrando cómo tienes ahora el código.

Comment: Lo que estoy viendo es que cuando insertas los usuarios, estas setetando el character set a UTF-8, pero luego cuando lees para comprobar el login, no lo haces. 
No estoy seguro si esto puede influir pero depende como esté configurado el mySQL.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado pero no me cabe en estos comentarios, lo escrito como respuesta. Agradeceria si vieran algun error en la explicacion lo informen porfavor, para poder editarlo lo mas rápido posible, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado, la verdad que no ha sido nada de las resoluciones comentadas, ha sido por un error sintactico y por unos cambios en la propia base de datos.

**Primer error detectado.** Resulta que en insertar_usuarios.php en la linea 39 el

`catch(Exception $e) {}`

estava mal escrito así Extcepcion.

**Segunda reparación/error**  Otra cosa que ocurria era que yo inserté un usuario de prueba y le encripté la contraseña pero sin pasar el tercer parametro el array cost

`$pass_cifrado = password_hash ( $contrasenia, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array ( "cost" => 12 ) );`

Y como conseqüencia, a la hora de desencriptar, pudiera ser que me hiciera que el bucle retornara falso.

**Tercer error.** Y por ultimo ya, cuando estuve buscando a cerca de este problema, leí en algun lugar, que al cifrar la contraseña tenía que poner en el campo de la BBDD 'PASSWORD' el utf español y cambiar la longitud de admision de caracteres en varchar(), de 20 caracteres a 255.

**Aplicación de la solución** Al hacer todos estos cambios continuadamente, y no parara de dar false, y con todos estos cambios aplicados, tuve la idea de borrar todos los usuarios de prueba de la bbdd desde la clave primaria para vaciar todos los campos, y a partir de ahí, y con los parametros en orden y los nuevos registros en la bbdd acutalizados consegui el ansiado true. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]